# When App start is it possible to fetch data, then init my modules with the fetched data using forRoot?

Tags: angular

I would like to send configuration data to my modules using forRoot.

Does `APP_INITIALIZER` can help me?

I would like to do something like:

```js
let config;

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ HttpClientModule, BrowserModule, SomeModule.forRoot({config:config}) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, UserComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [ UserService,ConfigService,
  {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
        return configService.load().then((_config)=>{
          console.log(_config)
config = _config;

        })
        }
        ,
      deps: [ConfigService],
      multi: true
    }]
})
```

How can I force **SomeModule** to wait for config to be ready?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone needs to know, I did it like this:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ HttpClientModule, BrowserModule, SomeModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, UserComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [ UserService,ConfigService,
  {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService, aService: ServiceInSomeModule) => {
        return configService.load().then((_config)=>{
ServiceInSomeModule.config = _config;

        })
        }
        ,
      deps: [ConfigService, ServiceInSomeModule],
      multi: true
    }]
})
```

The point here was to use the a service in **SomeModule** (*ServiceInSomeModule*) and add it in the dependencies of the Factory function in **APP_INITIALIZER **

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is any external way to tell the module to wait for the config,
but if you return a Promise from the factory method, the entire initialization process will wait for the Promise to resolve.

Comment: I think the code above already returns a promise in the factory method, isn't it?